# Go: multiple len() calls vs performance?

Tags: algorithm, go, micro-optimization

At the moment I am implementing some sorting algorithms. As it's in the nature of algorithms, there are a lot of calls on the length of some arrays/slices using the `len()` method.

Now, given the following code for a (part of) the Mergesort algorithm:

```
  for len(left) > 0 || len(right) > 0 {
        if len(left) > 0 && len(right) > 0 {
            if left[0] <= right[0] {
                result = append(result, left[0])
                left = left[1:len(left)]
            } else {
                result = append(result, right[0])
                right = right[1:len(right)]
            }
        } else if len(left) > 0 {
            result = append(result, left[0])
            left = left[1:len(left)]
        } else if len(right) > 0 {
            result = append(result, right[0])
            right = right[1:len(right)]
        }
    }
```

My question is: Do these multiple len() calls affect the performance of the algorithm negatively? Is it better to make a temporary variable for the length of the `right` and `left` slice? Or does the compiler does this itself?

Comment: when in doubt, benchmark and/or profile.

Comment: That's a strange question for code which does allocations. What would you answer if someone asked: "Does serving salted butter on an aircraft carrier raise the cost of missions?". Yes it does but it doesn't matter (assuming salted butter is more expensive).

Answer (score 81, accepted):

There are two cases:

- **Local slice:** length will be cached and there is no overhead
- **Global slice** or passed (by reference): length cannot be cached and there is overhead

#### No overhead for local slices

For locally defined slices the length is cached, so there is no runtime overhead. You can see this in the assembly of the following program:

```
func generateSlice(x int) []int {
    return make([]int, x)
}

func main() {
    x := generateSlice(10)
    println(len(x))
}
```

Compiled with `go tool 6g -S test.go` this yields, amongst other things, the following lines:

```
MOVQ    "".x+40(SP),BX
MOVQ    BX,(SP)
// ...
CALL    ,runtime.printint(SB)
```

What happens here is that the first line retrieves the length of `x` by getting the value located 40 bytes from the beginning of `x` and most importantly caches this value in `BX`, which is then used for every occurrence of `len(x)`. The reason for the offset is that an array has the following structure ([source](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/cmd/gc/go.h?name=go1.3.3#831)):

```
typedef struct
{               // must not move anything
    uchar   array[8];   // pointer to data
    uchar   nel[4];     // number of elements
    uchar   cap[4];     // allocated number of elements
} Array;
```

`nel` is what is accessed by `len()`. You can see this in the [code generation](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/cmd/6g/gsubr.c?name=go1.3.3#1302) as well.

#### Global and referenced slices have overhead

For shared values caching of the length is not possible since the compiler has to assume that the slice changes between calls. Therefore the compiler has to write code that accesses the length attribute directly every time. Example:

```
func accessLocal() int {
    a := make([]int, 1000) // local
    count := 0
    for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
        count += len(a)
    }
    return count
}

var ag = make([]int, 1000) // pseudo-code

func accessGlobal() int {
    count := 0
    for i := 0; i < len(ag); i++ {
        count += len(ag)
    }
    return count
}
```

Comparing the assembly of both functions yields the crucial difference that as soon as the variable is global the access to the `nel` attribute is not cached anymore and there will be a runtime overhead:

```
// accessLocal
MOVQ    "".a+8048(SP),SI // cache length in SI
// ...
CMPQ    SI,AX            // i < len(a)
// ...
MOVQ    SI,BX
ADDQ    CX,BX
MOVQ    BX,CX            // count += len(a)

// accessGlobal
MOVQ    "".ag+8(SB),BX
CMPQ    BX,AX            // i < len(ag)
// ...
MOVQ    "".ag+8(SB),BX
ADDQ    CX,BX
MOVQ    BX,CX            // count += len(ag)
```

Comment: great answer...and super awesome that Go compiler does this under the hood.

Comment: There's no synchronization in the function and therefore the go memory model allows the compiler to cache len() wherever the slice comes from. From the analysis in your answer, it appears that this is not an optimization that gc currently makes, but it could in future.

Comment: @Anonymous AFAICS yes. But even when the process is synchronized the compiler would need to add code to refresh the cached value after you passed the slice to another goroutine. The compiler would have to know where the synchronization happens and insert code to refresh the length below that.

Comment: Hi, in your function accessLocal, u are using the global variable ag and lot local variable a

Answer (score 11):

Despite the good answers you are getting, I'm getting poorer performance if calling len(a) constantly, for example in this test http://play.golang.org/p/fiP1Sy2Hfk

```
package main

import "testing"

func BenchmarkTest1(b *testing.B) {
    a := make([]int, 1000)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        count := 0
        for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
            count += len(a)
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkTest2(b *testing.B) {
    a := make([]int, 1000)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        count := 0
        lena := len(a)
        for i := 0; i < lena; i++ {
            count += lena
        }
    }
}
```

When run as `go test -bench=.` I get:

```
BenchmarkTest1   5000000               668 ns/op
BenchmarkTest2   5000000               402 ns/op
```

So there is clearly a penalty here, possibly because the compiler is making worse optimizations in compile-time.

Comment: For a fair comparison, the slice should also be a local variable.

Comment: It tried with a local variable and the results were the same. And if count is declared locally, the difference is important, but I don't know why.

Comment: @siritinga shared slices such as globals are treated differently and have a runtime overhead. I have updated my answer to cover this case.

Comment: @nemo Thank you for your reply. I've modified the code, now count and the slice are local, and the difference is still there. I can't read assembler so I don't know why, but the difference is there.

Comment: @siritinga Use `b.ResetTimer()` after the creation of the slice. You are measuring the slice creation time here. The second test is probably re-using the space of the first slice.

Comment: @nemo using `ResetTimer()` doesn't change the time. It is expected, because it is only allocated once per test so it is negligible. And if I switch the order, I'm getting the same result. So there is something else going on.

Comment: due to high voted @nemo's answer, a test for global array would be great helpful

Answer (score 1):

Hope things got improved in the latest version of Go

go version go1.16.7 linux/amd64

```
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: 001_test
cpu: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz
BenchmarkTest1-8     4903609           228.8 ns/op
BenchmarkTest2-8     5280086           229.9 ns/op
```

Comment: what do you want to say with that bench result ? Here the above benchmark got twice faster in 1.17.1 Vs 1.15 :l

Comment: go version go1.17.5 linux/amd64


BenchmarkTest1-8     4665556        253.3 ns/op

BenchmarkTest2-8     4493875        254.4 ns/op

Wonder how it is faster for you in 1.17.1, in 1.17.5 it is not faster, Also there is no significant penalty for using len